# How to install Kubuntu 22.04 LTS from live USB?

Tags: kubuntu, 22.04, live-usb, lts

I flashed the Kubuntu 22.04 ISO image on to a USB disk and booted my computer.  The Kubuntu wallpaper is shown on all screens but nothing else (I assume it's the Kubuntu wallpaper, it looks like a big Firefox logo).

What I have tried

- pushing the Windows key, nothing happened
- Pressing `Alt-Tab`And `Ctrl-Alt-Del`, which does absolutely nothing.
- Pressing Alt-f1 or f2 brings up the search bar at the top of the screen. I then typed `install kubuntu` but nothing starts when I click it.

Can someone please help me?

Comment: Follow the instructions from this site. https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/install-ubuntu-desktop#1-overview It is the same for KUbuntu

Comment: Try pressing shift on booting into the live image, and select the safe graphics mode.This happens to me all the time on my old laptops.

Comment: Did you verify the ISO prior to write to media?  I'm guessing the media self check didn't run, if I had a box act like what you did, I'd boot the media on a different box (even 2 or 3) and have the media self-check validate on those other boxes.  If it validated perfectly on the other boxes; I'd trust the media & concentrate on the box you're currently struggling with (*where I'd try booting a different stack...*)

Comment: Thank you @RishonJR, that will probably work. I've had trouble before with Linux on modern graphics cards when all the updates aren't installed. I'll use safe mode to start the installer and hopefully it'll run correctly once all graphics drivers are downloaded.

Comment: @guiverc, yes thanks, verified

Comment: @David, that's exactly what I'm trying to do...